# Conditional expectation random variable composed with a meas. function

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I know that the following is true and fairly easily proven.

Let $Y$ be a random variable and $\varphi$ a measurable function.

Let $A$ be a $\Sigma_Y$ measurable set.

If $ X (\omega) = \varphi(Y (\omega))$ for  all $\omega\in A  $ , then  $\mathbb{E}(X|Y )(\omega) = \varphi(Y (\omega))$ for almost all $\omega\in A  $

I cannot, however, come up with an example of a variable $Y$ and function $\varphi$ such that $ X (\omega) = \varphi(Y (\omega))$ for almost all $\omega\in A $ (and $A$ is not $\sigma(Y)$ measurable) but  $\mathbb{E}(X|Y )(\omega) = \varphi(Y (\omega))$ .

Could you help me with that?

EDIT: I'm looking for $Y$ such that for $A \not\in \sigma(Y)$,  $\omega \in A$ $$ X (\omega) = \varphi(Y (\omega))$$ but $$\mathbb{E}(X|Y )(\omega) \neq \varphi(Y (\omega))$$

Comment: Why would you want an example of that?

Comment: @Did Simply beacause I can prove that for $A$ measurable the statement is false and I do not see what could go wrong if I neglect that assumption. Is that so bad to be interested in a counterexample?

Comment: (Please slow down on the rhetorical questions.) The trouble is that one fails to imagine how $X\mathbf 1_A=\varphi(Y)\mathbf 1_A$ could be related to $E(X|Y)=\varphi(Y)$ except when $P(A)=1$. But perhaps you actually meant to ask for an example when $X\mathbf 1_A=\varphi(Y)\mathbf 1_A$ and $E(X|Y)\mathbf 1_A=\varphi(Y)\mathbf 1_A$ with $A$ not in $\sigma(Y)$? Trivial, choose $X=\varphi(Y)$. Or an example when $A=\{X=\varphi(Y)\}$ is not in $\sigma(Y)$ but is also $A=\{E(X|Y)=\varphi(Y)\}$? But then this is impossible since $\{E(X|Y)=\varphi(Y)\}$ is always in $\sigma(Y)$. Ad lib.

Comment: @Did I am looking for an example that the following implication $$\forall \omega \in A : X(\omega) = \varphi(Y(\omega)) \implies E(X|Y)(\omega) = \varphi(Y(\omega))$$ does not have to be true if $A \not\in \sigma(Y)$

Comment: You seem to be asking for some situation where a given assertion holds. What is this assertion, already? Please write it down without negation (at present these make impossible to understand what you are after).

Comment: @Did I've just edited my question. Could you take a look at it?